# JS как отобразить json в правильной кодировке?

Tags: javascript, кодировка, decode

Есть строка, которая закодированна в `UTF-8`, пример

```
var strjson = '{"Header": "\u0420\u040e\u0421\u0453\u0420\u0458\u0420\u0458\u0420\u00b0, \u0420\u0491\u0420\u0455\u0421\u0403\u0421\u201a\u0421\u0453\u0420\u0457\u0420\u0405\u0420\u00b0\u0421\u040f \u0420\u0491\u0420\u00bb\u0421\u040f \u0420\u0406\u0420\u0455\u0420\u00b7\u0420\u0406\u0421\u0402\u0420\u00b0\u0421\u201a\u0420\u00b0, \u0421\u0402\u0421\u0453\u0420\u00b1."}';
```

я передаю ее в `js` и декодирую так

```
var json = JSON.parse(strjson);
```

на что в консоли получаю

```
Header: "РЎСѓРјРјР°, РґРѕСЃС‚СѓРїРЅР°СЏ РґР»СЏ РІРѕР·РІСЂР°С‚Р°, СЂСѓР±."
```

хотя если я теперь пойду на любой сервис по декодеровке онлайн, [например](https://2cyr.com/decode/?lang=ru), и туда вставлю хоть исходную, хоть полученную 
я получу то что надо  (сервис говорит, исходная `UTF-8`,  отображается как windows-1251)

```
Header: "Сумма, доступная для возврата, руб."
```

почему так? как мне правильно распарсить полученный `json` в `js` браузера?

страничка написана в `utf8`

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

да и сам `html` файл в кодировке `utf8` открывая ее в блокноте я вижу у кирилицы теже загогулины, означает что текст тоже в `utf8`, в чем дело? 
Почему `js` отображает так ?

UPD.

Всем, спасибо, проблема была в delphi tsuperobject - он портил utf8 кодировку, сделал чтобы перед передачей ему декодировать в 1251 и проблема ушла. всем спасибо!

```
JSON := SO( Utf8ToAnsi( Data) );
```

Comment: Проблема явно в вашем "кодировщике", а вовсе не в JS, он то как раз делает то что и должен. Для справки: вот [список всех символов кириллицы в Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters#Cyrillic)  и, как видите, эти ваши "загогулины" тоже в него входят, под теми же номерами.

Comment: да поправил выходные данные, спасибо всем за участие

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в кодировщике. В json через `\u0000` должны указываться коды в UTF16, а у тебя что-то с UTF8. А вообще, кириллицу можно вообще слать как есть, а не превращать в коды.

```js
console.log([..."Сумма"].map(x => "\\u" + x.charCodeAt(0).toString(16).padStart(4, 0)).join(""))
console.log(JSON.parse('"\u0421\u0443\u043c\u043c\u0430"'))
console.log("\u0421\u0443\u043c\u043c\u0430")
console.log("\u0420\u040e\u0421\u0453\u0420\u0458\u0420\u0458\u0420\u00b0")
```

Comment: вобщем был прав, кодировку портил tsuperobject delphi я перед выдачей ему, кодирую в ansi     JSON := SO( Utf8ToAnsi(Data) ); JSON.SaveTo('json_table_ansi.json', true);  и стало как надо кодировать